How to merge roles in Postgres?
In my database I have two distinct roles which have no special attributes and thus do not inherit. They act as (RBAC) permissions, and there are policies for each permission on multiple tables.
How can the two roles be merged to a single role, in a way that does not require me to drop old policies and recreate them?
For instance, could I rename the second role to the name of the first role?

Grant both roles to a third one.

Thanks I thought about that. Maybe I was not clear about my goal. I would like to have fewer roles instead of more.

Perhaps you could describe your worries about policies in some more detail. Normally, REASSIGN OWNED would be the command you are looking for.

I didn't know about REASSIGN OWNED, but it seems that is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!
